# Series of views or series of activity?

Tags: android

I've made my first android app :-) There's only one activity, and, on events, I modify the root view of the unique activity. My GUI is a series of views inside an unique activity.

Perhaps it's best to do one activity with only one root view, and, when I want to show another view, create and launch another activity, with only one general view ?

If so, how to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally best to separate your app into distinct activities. Having everything in one Activity is not a good idea! And doing lots of View manipulation seems downright confusing...

Locate distinct operations in your app and separate them. You might for example have `LoginActivity`, `SearchActivity`, `ViewThingActivity`, `ManageThatActivity`, `PreferencesActivity`, and so on. It will make developing your app much simpler and easier to maintain!

Comment: Planty thanks. And, please, when I'm in LoginActivity, how I launch the MaganeThatActivity ?

Comment: You would do something like `startActivity(new Intent(this, MaganeThatActivity.class));`